# How to add PPPoE tag to a PADI packet using Go?

Tags: go, byte, packet, serializable, pppoe

This is how I create a PADI packet using `google/gopacket` library.

```
func createDefaultPADI() layers.PPPoE {
    return layers.PPPoE{
        Version:   0x1,
        Type:      0x1,
        Code:      layers.PPPoECodePADI,
        SessionId: 0x0000,
        Length:    0x00,
    }
}
```

Following structs are defined within the package.

```
type PPPoE struct {
    BaseLayer
    Version   uint8
    Type      uint8
    Code      PPPoECode
    SessionId uint16
    Length    uint16
}

// BaseLayer is a convenience struct which implements the LayerData and
// LayerPayload functions of the Layer interface.
type BaseLayer struct {
    // Contents is the set of bytes that make up this layer.  IE: for an
    // Ethernet packet, this would be the set of bytes making up the
    // Ethernet frame.
    Contents []byte
    // Payload is the set of bytes contained by (but not part of) this
    // Layer.  Again, to take Ethernet as an example, this would be the
    // set of bytes encapsulated by the Ethernet protocol.
    Payload []byte
}
```

Afterwards I serialize the packet as follows:

```
func serializePPPoEPacket(pppoe *layers.PPPoE) {
    buffer := gopacket.NewSerializeBuffer()
    options := gopacket.SerializeOptions{
        ComputeChecksums: true,
        FixLengths:       false,
    }

    ethernetLayer := &layers.Ethernet{
        SrcMAC:       net.HardwareAddr{0xca, 0x01, 0x03, 0x88, 0x00, 0x06},
        DstMAC:       net.HardwareAddr{0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff},
        EthernetType: layers.EthernetTypePPPoEDiscovery,
    }
    if err := gopacket.SerializeLayers(buffer, options, ethernetLayer, pppoe); err != nil {
        pppoeLogger.Error("serialize-error")
    }

    pkt := gopacket.NewPacket(buffer.Bytes(), layers.LayerTypePPPoE, gopacket.Default)
    log.Println("pkt: ", hex.EncodeToString(pkt.Data()))

}
```

The hex output of the packet is: `ffffffffffffca0103880006886311090000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

I want to add some PPPoE tags to the packet such as `vendor-specific tag` and `host-uniq` etc. I have tried to manipulate the payload as follows to see if it's gonna work:

```
// tried this
pppoe.BaseLayer.Payload = append(pppoe.BaseLayer.Payload, []byte("asdasd"))
pppoe.BaseLayer.Contents = append(pppoe.BaseLayer.Contents, []byte("asdasd"))
```

Nothing happened, I just can't append or set the payload properly. What would be the possible solution here?

In the comment section where `BaseLayer` is defined within the package, it says `set of bytes encapsulated by the Ethernet protocol` does that mean that I need to set them in `ethernet` layer or? If so, I have tried again somethink like that as follows:

```
// value here is just a byte array.
// ethernetLayer.Payload = append(ethernetLayer.Payload, value...)
```

Nothing worked again.
I want to be able to add `tags` to a `PPPoE` packet.